# Change <td> to <input> using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have problem with my code, I want change  to  by  id

this is my PHP

```
<?php
    foreach($brands->result() as $row){
?>
    <tr id ="<?=$row->brand_id?>">
        <td><?=$row->brand_id;?></td>
        <td class="editableName"><?=$row->name_brand;?></td>
        <td class="editableDesc"><?=$row->description;?></td>
        <td>
            <button id="edit" class="form-control">Edit</button>
            <a href="<?=base_url('Admin/brands/delete')?>/<?=$row->brand_id;?>"><button class="form-control">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php 
    } 
?>
```

This is my JQuery

```
$('#edit').click(function () {
    $(this).parents('tr').find('td.editableName').each(function() {
        var html = $(this).html();
        var input = $('<input name="name" class="form-control" type="text" />');
        input.val(html);
        $(this).html(input);
    });
    $(this).parents('tr').find('td.editableDesc').each(function() {
        var html = $(this).html();
        var input = $('<input name="description" class="form-control" type="text" />');
        input.val(html);
        $(this).html(input);
    });
});
```

i am using that jquery script its only work on 1st row, the nth row doesn't work

Comment: You're re-using `id` values in your HTML.  `id` is supposed to be unique.  The jQuery selector is only finding the *first* one because there shouldn't be more.  You should probably use a `class` value instead of an `id`.

Comment: You should change button selector on class or add onclick for each button. You cannot use same id names.

Comment: so i change the `<tr id>` to `<tr class>` like that?

Comment: change `<button id="edit" class="form-control">Edit</button>` to `<button class="edit form-control">Edit</button>` and on js use `$('.edit').click(`

Comment: thanks @Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: You're welcome @TukangSihir :-)